# Typescript cannot find interface name

Tags: typescript, aurelia

In my Typescript file *(which is a part of Aurelia View-Model)*, I have following structure:

```
import {Chart} from './chart';

interface IMargin {
    top: number, right: number, bottom: number, left: number
}

export class App{

    chartOptions: any;

    constructor(margin: IMargin) { // No error here

        this.chartOptions = {
            element: "#chart",
            margin: IMargin    // Error: Cannot find name "IMargin"
        };
    }

    attached() {
        var chart = new Chart(this.chartOptions);
        chart.addChart();
    }
}
```

`Typescript` compiler has no problem with using interface in the constructor, but it gives the error `Cannot find name "IMargin"` when I use it to define `margin` inside the constructor. Why is that?

Also, Where is the best place to declare interfaces, if this is not the correct way? Thank you.

Comment: You're assigning the interface to this.chartOptions.margin, if you want to assign the parameter margin you need to write this.chartOptions = { element: '#chart', margin: margin };

Comment: No, the parameter `margin` is just to show the contrast that the `IMargin` interface is available in the parameter of the constructor but not available inside the constructor itself. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 4):

Change it like this

```
export class App{

    chartOptions: any;

    constructor(margin: IMargin) { // No error here

        // instead of this
        //this.chartOptions = {
        //    element: "#chart",
        //    margin: IMargin    // Error: Cannot find name "IMargin"
        //};

        // use this
        this.chartOptions = {
            element: "#chart",
            margin: margin
        } as { element: string, margin: IMargin };
```

I used the `as` to show how we can assure TS about the type.. but that is not needed. The point is, assign to property `margin` passed paramater **margin**

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is the `as` a feature in Typescript or is it ES6?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're trying to assign the `margin` property of the chart object to a value of an interface, which isn't a valid value. You need to set the property to a valid value, like a `string`, `number`, `object`, etc.

I was banging my head against the wall with this a while back and didn't realize that was the issue. So, to accomplish what you're wanting to do what Radim Kohler said. Either set the value of margin to the passed in param like so:

```
constructor(margin: IMargin) {
     this.chartOptions = {   
          element: "#chart",
          margin: margin
     };
}
```

Or you can create a variable of IMargin type and set the property to the variable like so:

```
constructor(margin: IMargin) {
     var myMarginInterfaceObject: IMargin = margin;
     // then you can do some editing on the obj if you want here;

     this.chartOptions = {   
          element: "#chart",
          margin: myMarginInterfaceObject
     };
}
```

When I use interaces (I generally just use classes now), I had a folder that held all of all my interface files. It kept it clean and I always knew where to look for them. It also made all of my (interface) import statements very structured because they all came from the same location.

I've created a GistRun to help you visualize some stuff:
https://gist.run/?id=df782959b005308b3b095c8df569574a

Comment: wow, thank you so much for the detailed explanation and for the gist. So to summarize, we can not assign a derived type such as `Interface` as a type to a variable ***inside an object***? is that right?

Comment: @akshayKhot Well, if you CAN assign a type to a property in the object, I don't know how. However, using the syntax of "propertyname": value is what you are doing. So you are using the interface in place of the value and that's not valid.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Radim Köhler's answer, you can also do something like following:

```
interface IMargin {
    top: number, right: number, bottom: number, left: number
}

interface IMarginWrapper{
    element:string, margin:IMargin
}

export class App{

    //instead of any specify your type properly here
    chartOptions: {element:string, margin:IMargin}; //alternative#1
    chartOptions1: IMarginWrapper;                  //alternative#2

    constructor(margin: IMargin) {

        //usage does not change much

        this.chartOptions = {
            element: "#chart",
            margin: margin
        };

        this.chartOptions1 = {
            element: "#chart",
            margin: margin
        };
    }
}
```